# IIS changes domian in href attribute of a(link) tags

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have the following code in one aspx file:

```
<a href="<%# myfunction() %>" ...
```

myfunction returns a very simple string like this:

```
return "http://domain.com/link";
```

Locally the code runs smoothly, however, when I migrate it to the production environment. All the href attributes are changed to: `http://serverdomain.com/link`

This is very strange to me, I have done this several times before. I do not know what I am doing wrong this time.

Does any one have any idea about what I am missing?

Comment: Can you post the code of your function that generates the link? I suspect the problem is there, not in you aspx markup.

Comment: @fotijr  The function is just what you see in the post. A simple return of a concatenated string. Moreover,  I found something new, if I return a string without 'http://' the server will write something like this: 'http://serverdomain.com/domain.com/link'

Comment: there's no code in your post, I'm asking to see the code from `myfunction()` that builds the href string.

Comment: Oh, you're just returning a static string? You have the domain hard-coded?

Comment: Yes the domain is static. It is like this: return "http://domain.com/link?param=" + someVariable; @fotijr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS isn't causing any effect here, the behavior is defined by the HTML spec. For navigation links, there are four common conventions an href attribute can follow:

1. **Beginning with `http://` or `//`.** The browser will resolve the link as an absolute URL.
2. **Beginning with a single `/`.** The browser will resolve the link as relative to the domain.
3. **Beginning with text.** The browser will resolve the link as relative to the page.
4. **Beginning with `#`.** The browser will look for an HTML element on the same page (by ID) and scroll to it if found.

I would compare the strings of the return value of your function, and the actual HTML markup rendered (not just what is navigated to or shown on hover).

To use an example on this page:

`<a href="/questions">Questions</a>` is a relative URL, which resolves to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions`.

`<a href="http://example.com/questions">Questions</a>` is an absolute URL, and resolves to an external domain at `http://example.com/questions`.

Per one of your comments, the value your function would create a relative URL. If `<a href="domain.com/link?param=">` was on this page, it would resolve https://stackoverflow.com/ as the domain.